# Error while making call to facebook login dialogue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a Facebook web-app to stream Facebook data. To invoke a facebook Login dialogue  we need to make a Get request to the following URI:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth?client_id=my-app-id&redirect_uri=http://my-host-ip:8081&state={"{st=state123abc,ds=123456789}"}
```

On hitting it on postman I am getting the proper Facebook login page but when I hit this URI from browser I am getting 403 forbidden.

Comment: You did not really place double quotes around the redirect_uri value, and leave all the line breaks in, right?

Comment: No, I didn't add any quotes. I'll edit my question.

Comment: `state` doesn’t need any {} or quotes either, it is just supposed to be a random value for CSRF protection. If you are getting an error, then that might be due to parameter values not being URL-encoded properly, so try that first.